# Value of が at the end of interrogative sentences

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-が, interrogatives

I know there are other questions on this site about が and けど at the end of a sentence, but I couldn't find one about interrogative sentences. Context: in a manga, person A said something that his friend (person B) interpreted as a joke. The dialogue continues as follows:

> Person A: だって８割はホントだもん。
>
> Person B: へぇー　８割本音を言わない男が？

I don't understand the meaning of the second sentence. In particular, I don't understand why there's a negative verb and the value of が. Was something left out? I feel like there could be a じゃなかった after が. Person A in the manga is a reserved type, so I thought it could be translated as:

> "Weren't you the type that doesn't say 80% of his true feelings?"

Is my guess right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That が is a subject marker, and the corresponding predicate is omitted.

> A: だって8割はホントだもん。
>
> B: へぇー　8割本音を言わない男が（8割もホントのことを言うの／そんなに本音で喋ったの）?
>     The person who doesn't say his true feelings 80% of the time (says that much truth this time)?

But it would be too wordy if you tried to translate this literally, so your translation attempt seems fine to me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the examples in brackets you put the verb in positive form, why is it negative in the original?

Comment: Do you understand that 言わない is just a relative clause that modifies 男? The predicate of the main clause is omitted (and non-negative).

Answer (score 1):

> Person A: だって８割はホントだもん。
>   Person B: へぇー　８割本音を言わない男が？

The following your guess is not right/correct.

> "Weren't you the type that doesn't say 80% of his true feelings?"

As you guessed **something was left out** in the sentence by Person B.
The full sentence might be like:

> Person B: へぇー　８割本音を言わない男が 「**８割はホントだ」と言うのは疑{うたが}わしいくないか** ？
>   *Huh, isn't it doubtful that the man who does not say the 80% true intention says "80% is true"?*
>   *Huh, isn't it doubtful that you say "80% is true" who usually hide the 80% of your true intention"?*

In this context, I think, Person B used **男{おとこ}** in stead of **you**.

Answer (score 0):

The end of the question was dropped and assumed obvious.
This is often the case in Japanese and many phrase parts get dropped all the time.

I don't have enough context to tell you more about your case, but here is an example in English.

> A : 80% of men are perverts!
>   B : WHAT!? 80% of men are? <-the last word, "**pervert**", was dropped.

Answer (score 0):

> Person A: だって８割はホントだもん。
>
> Person B: へぇー　８割本音を言わない男が？

So little context to be sure, but my best guess is Person A is arguing what the 男 have said or done is 80% based on reality and Person B jokes by saying the man usually says only 20% of his real thought.

As for the が, what is supposed to follow it is "８割はホント(の事言ったの？)" or something like that.